# Не устанавливается discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord-api

Посмотрел много видео по созданию дискорд ботов.
Думаю, проблема в том, что при выполнении в консоли команды `npm install discrod.js`
в конце вместо 17-18, как во всех статьях, у меня выдаёт 0.
В чём проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скопируйте текст из консоли в google translate.

Comment: Ну тут пишет что у меня нету узлов и что npm WARN устарела snekfetch@3.6.4: используйте взамен node-fetch

Comment: npm WARN saveError ENOENT: такого файла или каталога нет, откройте «C: \ Windows \ system32 \ package.json»
Уведомление npm создало файл блокировки как package-lock.json. Вы

Comment: должны зафиксировать этот файл.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: нет такого файла или каталога, откройте «C: \ Windows \ system32 \ package.json»
npm WARN discord.js@11.4.2 требует однорангового узла bufferutil@^3.0.3, но ни один не установлен. Вы должны установить одноранговые зависимости самостоятельно.

Comment: npm ПРЕДУПРЕЖДЕНИЕ discord.js@11.4.2 требует однорангового узла erlpack @ discordapp / erlpack, но ни один из них не установлен. Вы должны установить одноранговые зависимости самостоятельно.
npm ПРЕДУПРЕЖДЕНИЕ discord.js@11.4.2 требует однорангового узла node-opus@^0.2.7, но ни один не установлен. Вы должны установить одноранговые зависимости самостоятельно.
npm WARN discord.js@11.4.2 требует однорангового узла opusscript@^0.0.6, но ни один не установлен. Вы должны установить одноранговые зависимости самостоятельно.
npm ПРЕДУПРЕЖДЕНИЕ discord.js@11.4.2 требует однорангового узла

Comment: натрия@^2.0.3, но ни один не установлен. Вы должны установить одноранговые зависимости самостоятельно.
npm WARN Для discord.js@11.4.2 требуется одноранговый узел libsodium-wrappers@^0.7.3, но ни один из них не установлен. Вы должны установить одноранговые зависимости самостоятельно.
npm ПРЕДУПРЕЖДЕНИЕ discord.js@11.4.2 требует однорангового узла uws@^9.14.0, но ни один не установлен. Вы должны установить одноранговые зависимости самостоятельно.
npm WARN system32 Нет описания
npm WARN system32 Нет поля репозитория.
npm WARN system32 Нет данных README
npm WARN system32 Нет поля лицензии.

Comment: + discord.js@11.4.2
добавлено 8 пакетов от 7 участников и проверено 8 пакетов за 22.682 с
найдено 0 уязвимостей

Comment: И почему вы тогда решили что у вас не установился пакет? Вы попробовали что-то сделать? _discord.js@11.4.2 добавлено 8 пакетов от 7 участников и проверено 8 пакетов за 22.682 с найдено 0 уязвимостей_ - установилось.

Comment: Ну я пробую запустить бота node /Desktop/Discord_bot/bot.js пишет что не устоновленные модули

Comment: внутренний / модули / CJS / loader.js: 611
    бросить ошибку;
    ^

Comment: Ошибка: не удается найти модуль 'C: \ Desktop \ botet \ bot.js'
    в Function.Module._resolveFilename (внутренний / modules / cjs / loader.js: 609: 15)
    в Function.Module._load (внутренняя / modules / cjs / loader.js: 535: 25)
    в Function.Module.runMain (внутренняя / modules / cjs / loader.js: 797: 12)
    at executeUserCode (внутренний / bootstrap / node.js: 526: 15)
    при startMainThreadExecution (внутренний / bootstrap / node.js: 439: 3)

Comment: Зачем Вы пытаетесь установить discord.js в Windows\System32?

Comment: Ну я попробывал через cmd потом 32

Comment: Но я чуть тупанул, и оказывается оно уже давно устоновилось

Comment: Но запускаться не хочет

Comment: Нужно закрыть, человек не читает инструкции

Comment: Спасибо что помогли..

Comment: [Хороший пример](https://gist.github.com/eslachance/3349734a98d30011bb202f47342601d3) - сделайте как пишут, всё работает.